# How to apply css to an element on when the user scrolls by it and it becomes stuck to the top of the viewport

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have a table in my viewport, and when the user scrolls through it, I want the table head to "stick" to the top of the viewport. I want to add a box shadow only when the table head becomes sticky.

Any ideas of how to do this? On the table heads I want to apply this to, I created an x-ref="funky". This is where that "funky" ref comes in.

I am going to wrap the table heads in a div where I will write the Alpine. Below is that div.

```
<div
  x-data="{ test: $refs.funky }" 
  x-init=
  "
    console.log(test)
    console.log(window.pageYOffset)
  "
>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

```
<div
  x-data="{ test: $refs.funky }" 
  x-init=
  "
    console.log(test)
    console.log(window.pageYOffset)
  "
>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sadly unfamiliar with syntax you are using here, but what you could do in vanilla JS would be:

1. Finding out what's the elements position relative to the page

```js
const element = document.getElementById("YOUR_ID")
const elementBounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

2. Getting current scroll position

```js
addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  console.log(window.scrollY);
});
```

3. Adding a class to the element when `elementBounding.top` is less than your current scroll

```js
if (elementBounding.top < window.scrollY) {
  element.classList.add("fix");
} else {
  element.classList.remove("fix");
}
```

So combined together it would look something like this:

```js
const element = document.getElementById("test");
const elementBounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  if (elementBounding.top < window.scrollY) {
    element.classList.add("fix");
  } else {
    element.classList.remove("fix");
  }
});
```

And then of course you must have a class .fix that can do something like that. So something like this:

```
.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Here is the sanbox for it:

[image: Edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74392996]